# Open a certain HealthKit screen in iOS within React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, healthkit

My React Native-driven app needs a user to subscribe for some health provider to fetch their medical records. To do that, my app should open a screen where a user can see a list of providers and choose those they need.

That screen might be reached by a path "iOS Desktop -> Health -> Health Data -> Health Records" which is pretty deep. How can I know a URL of that path to open it from my app using linking API?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has some documentation on their URL schema but overall it goes like `health://` as the baseline

Checkout https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/#built-in-url-schemes if you're using expo

and here if not - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html